# How to define build configurations for different API base URLs in UWP Project VS2015?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp, buildconfiguration

I have started building a UWP application. In it, I am going to have different API deployments which changes the BaseURL like following:

```
//DEV Api
public const string BaseURL = "http://mydevapi.com/devApi";
//Test Api
public const string BaseURL = "http://mytestapi.com/testApi";
//UAT Api
public const string BaseURL = "http://myuatapi.com/uatApi";
//Live Api
public const string BaseURL = "http://myliveapi.com/LiveApi";
```

So basically I want a way to change the baseURL on dynamically based on what kind of build I am making i.e. Dev, Test or Live.

I have previous experience of iOS and in XCode we create different [schemes](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/XcodeConcepts/Concept-Schemes.html) for this purpose.

I have seen the documentation and I think the best bet I have in c# and Visual studio is [Build configuration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwybya3w.aspx) as it is described as:

> You can create several build configurations for a solution. For
>   example, you can configure a debug build that your testers can use to
>   find and fix problems, and you can configure different kinds of builds
>   that you can distribute to different customers.

I have created a new build configuration named "AppName.Dev" but how can I use it to change the baseURL constant to Dev url?

This might come off as a basic question and shows my inexperience with c# and Visual studio but I can't figure out how do I make it materialize even after reading the documentation on it. Help a fella out?

**EDIT:** After reading [this article](http://haacked.com/archive/2007/09/16/conditional-compilation-constants-and-asp.net.aspx/), I have created four different configurations and defined conditional compilation symbols like following:

[image]

I have now used the defined compilation symbols in my constants file like this:

```
public const string BaseURL = "";
#if DEV
public const string BaseURL = "http://mydevapi.com/devApi";
#elif TEST
public const string BaseURL = "http://mytestapi.com/testApi"
#elif UAT
public const string BaseURL = "http://myuatapi.com/uatApi"
#elif LIVE
public const string BaseURL = "http://myliveapi.com/LiveApi";
#endif
```

The symbols however don't seem to be working as it returns empty string for baseURL even though I am running it in DEV configuration. Will update when I sort it out.

**EDIT 2:** Figured it out. I had two projects in my solution and I was defining configs and their symbols in one project while using them in the other. Posting an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add the build configurations like this, follow the following steps:

1. Select your project.
2. Go to <kbd>build</kbd>-><kbd>configuration manager</kbd>
3. From Active Solution configuration drop down, select <kbd>New...</kbd>
4. Name your new configuration and select whether it copies settings from Debug, release, ad hoc, App store or none based on your needs.
    [image]
5. Add settings such as whether this configuration is for build/deploy
   or both, the preferred platform etc. as per your needs.
6. Repeat step 4 & 5 for as many build configurations as you want to define.

This concludes adding new build configuration. The next part is to define conditional compilation symbols. For that, follow the following steps:

1. Collapse your project tree.
2. Locate Properties dropdown.
3. Right click it and click <kbd>Open</kbd>.
4. A properties menu will open.
5. Select <kbd>Build</kbd> from the side menu.
6. From the top drop down labelled <kbd>Configuration</kbd>, select your defined build configuration.
7. Properties of that configuration will open below. In the textfield labelled "Conditional Compilation symbols", define as many symbols as you want, separated by `;`.

Consult the following screenshot if you have any confusions:

[image]

With this part done, you can use your defined symbols in your API constants file like:

```
#if DEV
public const string BaseURL = "http://mydevapi.com/devApi";
#elif TEST
public const string BaseURL = "http://mytestapi.com/testApi"
#elif UAT
public const string BaseURL = "http://myuatapi.com/uatApi"
#elif LIVE
public const string BaseURL = "http://myliveapi.com/LiveApi";
#endif
```

Here, DEV, TEST, UAT and LIVE are my defined configurations.

Comment: When I debug in Release mode the program is very slow and has been compiling

Comment: I can't belive that (at the time of writing) I must hardcode all my urls without a proper app.config file (like WebApi projects). This should be an easy task...

Comment: @GianniB. I never worked on WebApis so I'd not know. You can say this is just a crude work-around that a new UWP dev found to get things in gear. If you happen to find a better way, I'd really appreciate if you could link me to it. Might be able to fix this is in my app.

Comment: I don't blame your solution, I blame Microsoft to not provide us an easier solution on UWP application.
Btw, my approch is to create a file (txt, key/value, json whatever you want) for each build (eg. Debug.confg, Test.config, Production.config) in which I will store my variables (eg. api url) and than hardcode the name of the file and use the conditional compilation symbols. To read a file for your UWP app (you have to use Windows API), I suggest you to read [this blog article](http://amadeusw.com/iot/custom-resource-files-in-uwp-windows-10). This will allow you to edit url without recompile